# Public access to objects propery on aurelia validation

Tags: aurelia

I would do like to have public access the private property where objects are stored on the current ValidationController as when we issue addObject().

From this blog:

http://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Jan/24/aurelia-validation/

I am trying to validate not only a WELL KNOWN object but ***ALL objects*** registered in the ValidationController

Let me explain a little bit, I had an interface called

```
export interface IRuleValidator {
  addRules(model:any): void;
}
```

and classes that implement such interface

```
export class AddressRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  addRules(address: Address) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((a: Address) => a.address)
      .required()
      .on(address);
  }
}

export class EmailRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  addRules(email: Email) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((e: Email) => e.email)
      .required()
      .on(email);
  }
}

export class PhoneRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  addRules(phone: Phone) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((p: Phone) => p.phone)
      .required()
      .on(phone);
  }
}

@inject(AddressRuleValidator, PhoneRuleValidator, EmailRuleValidator)
export class PlayerRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  private readonly addressRuleValidator: IRuleValidator;
  private readonly phoneRuleValidator: IRuleValidator;
  private readonly emailRuleValidator: IRuleValidator;
  constructor(addressRuleValidator: IRuleValidator, phoneRuleValidator: IRuleValidator, emailRuleValidator: IRuleValidator) {
    this.addressRuleValidator = addressRuleValidator;
    this.phoneRuleValidator = phoneRuleValidator;
    this.emailRuleValidator = emailRuleValidator;
  }
  addRules(player: Player) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((p: Player) => p.firstName)
      .required()
      .on(player);
    if (player.addresses && player.addresses.length > 0)
      player.addresses.map(address => this.addressRuleValidator.addRules(address));
    if (player.phones && player.phones.length > 0)
      player.phones.map(phone => this.phoneRuleValidator.addRules(phone));
    if (player.emails && player.emails.length > 0)
      player.emails.map(email => this.emailRuleValidator.addRules(email));
  }
}

@inject(PlayerRuleValidator)
export class ScoreRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  private readonly playerRuleValidator: IRuleValidator;
  constructor(playerRuleValidator: IRuleValidator) {
    this.playerRuleValidator = playerRuleValidator;
  }
  addRules(score: Score) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((s: Score) => s.factor)
      .required()
      .on(score);
    if (score.player) { this.playerRuleValidator.addRules(score.player); }
  }
}
```

Each class knows how to validate the object passed to it and delegates to other classes the validation of "*child*" objects.

i.e.: score has a player and a player has emails.

Score knows how to validate to itself and delegates to player his own validation and player do the same with emails, phones, buildin all "*the chain*" down.

Thus the entire process of building a "*validation chain*" starts calling addRules() on the root object of the graph.

Suppose that we have an score object: We resolve from "*the container*" a ruleValidator for Score and starts buildind the validation chain as follows.

```
@inject(ScoreRuleValidator)
export class ScoreList extends BaseViewModel {

  public isOk: boolean;
  public score: Score

................  code removed for brevity (validation controller code )

  @inject(ScoreRuleValidator)    
  constructor(ruleValidator: IRuleValidator) {

................  code removed for brevity (validation score object creation)

ruleValidator.addRules(this.score) //this call will start all the validation chain registration

this.validationController.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.changeOrBlur;
this.validationController.subscribe(event => this.validateAll())
  }

}

  private  validateAll() {


    this.validator
      .validateObject(this.model)
      .then(results => this.isOk = results.every(result => result.valid));

    //HERE GOES THE PROBLEM SINCE ONLY SCORE is known, and what about score.player, and score.player.addresss[], score.player.phones[], score.player.emails[] and so on in the graph
    //I WILL NEED to traverse all the chain and since ValidationController has track of those object will be greet to have access to them

}
```

HERE GOES THE PROBLEM SINCE ONLY SCORE is known, and what about score.player, and score.player.addresss[], score.player.phones[], score.player.emails[] and so on in the graph?.

I WILL NEED to traverse all the chain and since ValidationController has track of those object ***will be great*** to have access to it.

Meanwile an option is refactor the interface a rewrite the validator classes as follows:

```
export interface IRuleValidator {
  addRules(model:any, models:any[]): void;
}
```

and pass an empty array from the root of the chain collecting all those objects.. like so..

```
export class AddressRuleValidator implements IRuleValidator {
  addRules(address: Address, models: any[]) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((a: Address) => a.type)
      .required()
      .on(address);

    models.push(address);

  }
```

and kick the process.. with an empty array []

```
 const objects: any[] = [];
 ruleValidator.addRules(this.score, [])
```

But since we alreay have this property private on the ValidationController, **please make it public**.. (*I will take care of not touching it, just read it*)

BR

(then... the final method for validateAll should be like this)

```
  private async validateAll() {
    for (let model of this.models) {
      let results = await this.validator.validateObject(model);
      if (results.some(result => !result.valid)) {
        this.isOk = false;
        return;
      }
    }
    this.isOk = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A deep look to the callback  is the answer.

```
validationController.subscribe(event => this.validateAll())
```

the event object passed to the callback is an array of ValidateResult[]
the ValidateResult type implements the following interface.

```
export declare class ValidateResult {
    rule: any;
    object: any;
    propertyName: string | null;
    valid: boolean;
    message: string | null;
    private static nextId;
    /**
     * A number that uniquely identifies the result instance.
     */
    id: number;
    /**
     * @param rule The rule associated with the result. Validator implementation specific.
     * @param object The object that was validated.
     * @param propertyName The name of the property that was validated.
     * @param error The error, if the result is a validation error.
     */
    constructor(rule: any, object: any, propertyName: string | null, valid: boolean, message?: string | null);
    toString(): string | null;
}
```

so the object/s validated is already there in the event object
we could simplyfy the code as follow to update a field to signal if the htlm for is ready.

```
this.validationController.subscribe(validateEvent => this.isFormValid = validateEvent.results.every(result => result.valid));
```